# QGLWidget rendering area not resizing proprely

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am developing an OpenGL application using Qt.  Until yesterday I was subclassing `QOpenGLWidget` to create my custom widget but after adding It to the main application which is a `QMainWindow`  with a few buttons and three `QGraphicsView` it ran really slow. I have tried using `QGLWidget` and the application runs the same as without the OpenGL widget.

The problem I have is that the widget that I've made subclassing `QGLWidget` does not resize properly (or at least the OpenGL rendering area doesn't).

I will give you an example using hellogl2 example from Qt 5.5.

Using `QOpenGLWidget` I get:

https://s32.postimg.org/u136s54ld/QOpen_GLWidget.png

Using `QGLWidget` I get:

https://s32.postimg.org/ahylis5tt/QGLWidget.png

I just changed the parent class from `QOpenGLWidget` to `QGLWidget` the rest of the code is the same. The same thing happens in my aplication.

I have tried to find a solution but I could not. May someone tell me why is this happening and how to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `QGLWidget` it is old stuff left for backward compatibility, for new projects don't use `QGL...` classes, instead use `QOpenGL...`

Comment: @ddriver I have read here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/29994/solved-qwindow-qopenglcontext-vs-qmainwindow-qglwidget/7  that when using ```QMainWindow``` is better to use ```QGLWidget``` That is why I have used it.

Comment: need more codez... What you observe is probably due to an incorrect update of the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, its a good idea to stick with the up to date approach and stay away from depricated code as suggested by @ddriver.

Having said that I have written a lot of code using the QGLWidget and there is no problem with it. It does everything I need so I stick with it for now.

Here is the main issue with your approach. You took the hellogl example from qt 5.5 and simply replaced the parent from QOpenGLWidget to QGLWidget. Unfortunately they don't handle resize events similarly.

QOpenglGLWidget does change the viewport based on the width and height given by the resize event as mentioned (not so clearly with a double negative) in their documentation. Link : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#resizeGL
check function `resizeEvent()` which in turn invokes `resizeGL()`.

Now the QGL widget does not do this for you. All it does is makes the opengl context current which means you have to handle it old school style calling `glViewport()` inside the `resizeGL()` function. I have copied a code snippet from the hellogl example from qt4.8

```
void GLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    int side = qMin(width, height);
    glViewport((width - side) / 2, (height - side) / 2, side, side);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
#ifdef QT_OPENGL_ES_1
    glOrthof(-0.5, +0.5, -0.5, +0.5, 4.0, 15.0);
#else
    glOrtho(-0.5, +0.5, -0.5, +0.5, 4.0, 15.0);
#endif
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Here is a link for qt4.8 version of the hellogl : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-opengl-hellogl-example.html

Notice how the `glViewport()` is called to resize the framebuffer inside the `resizeGL()` function. This is done automatically by the newer QOpenGLWidget even before reaching this function. If you choose to stick with QGLWidget, you need to handle this yourself.

There may be other subtle differences as well which you will need to figure out.

Comment: You were right! Calling ```glViewport``` in resizeGL solves the problem. I choose to use ```QGLWidget``` because for some reason when using ```QOpenGLWidget``` my whole program ran slower. Thank you!

Comment: This might well be an issue due to Qt handling some of the regular stuff and code ported will have redundant calls such as `glViewport()` to achieve a better control. If this is the case then its a big issue if the performance difference is that noticeable.